# Sum of elements of the set of cosets of a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian group and $H$ $\subset$ $G$ a subgroup. For two elements $a,b$ $\in$ $G/H$, define $a+b$ and prove that it is well-defined.

$G/H$ is the set of cosets of $H$ in $G$.

Please can anyone help me out here?

Comment: It depends. Do you plan to remove this question too, after getting an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Normally we would write the elements in $G/H$ as $g+H$ where $g$ is an element of $G$.
Note that $G/H=\{g+H\;|\; g\in G\}$.

The operation defined on $G/H$ is $$(a+H)+(b+H)=(a+b)+H$$ where $a+H,b+H\in G/H$.

To prove that the operation is well-defined, we need to show that if $a_1+H=a_2+H$ and $b_1+H=b_2+H$ then $$(a_1+H)+(b_1+H)=(a_2+H)+(b_2+H)$$
This means that the choice of different representative of same coset does not affect the operation.

Theorem:

> $$a+H=b+H \iff -b+a\in H$$

Since $a_1+H=a_2+H$, we have $-a_2+a_1\in H$. Similarly we have $-b_2+b_1\in H$.
Note that $-(b_2+a_2)+(a_1+b_1)=(-b_2+b_1)+(-a_2+a_1)\in H$.
Thus $a_1+b_1+H=a_2+b_2+H$, which means that $(a_1+H)+(b_1+H)=(a_2+H)+(b_2+H)$.

For further exercise, you can try to do it for multiplication, and also the case when $G$ is non-abelian but $H$ is normal in $G$.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can show that if $G$ is a group and $H$ is a normal subgroup, meaning $gH= Hg$ for all $g \in G$, then
$$aH \cdot bH = (ab)H$$
is well-defined and puts a group structure on $G/H$.

You must show that if $aH = a'H$ and $bH = b'H$, then
$$(ab)H = (a'b')H.$$
Since $H$ is normal this equivalent to
$$H = (a'b')H(b^{-1}a^{-1})$$
This holds because $aH = a'H$ and $bH = b'H$ is equivalent to
$$H = a'Ha^{-1} = b'Hb^{-1}.$$

If $G$ is abelian, then all subgroups are normal.